# unable to append div with multiple images with for loop

Tags: jquery, filereader

i just try to append a div with multiple images, my code is:

```
$('#imagess').change(function()
    {
        var leng=this.files.length;
        var reader=new FileReader();
        for(i=0; i<leng;i++)
        {
            reader.onload=function(e)
            {
                //alert('<img src='+e.target.result+'/>');
                $('#blah').append('<img src='+e.target.result+' width=60 height=60 />');
                //$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
        }


    });
```

its only showing one image always....

Comment: maybe try adding a jsfiddle

Comment: did you try looking at the console for errors? also, do the images have any positioning that might affect what you see?(absolute?) In short, does the markup append them even though you only see a single image?

JSfiddle can help aswell

Comment: actually..whenever i am uploading file for loop working only two time....even i have selected more the four images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating one reader and using it over and over. Try creating a new one each iteration:

```
$('#imagess').change(function()
{
    var leng=this.files.length;        
    for(i=0; i<leng;i++)
    {
        var reader=new FileReader();
        reader.onload=function(e)
        {
            //alert('<img src='+e.target.result+'/>');
            $('#blah').append('<img src='+e.target.result+' width=60 height=60 />');
            //$('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[i]);
    }


});
```

Comment: Yup. Good little tutorial here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files